# Header for Sound alerts, iOS. I want to make a sound play each time my app game reaches 5 minutes?

Tags: ios, audio, header, ipod

What is the header file for iOS sound alert, and sound management. I want to make my iTouch game to play a sound each time the player reaches 5 minutes into the game?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
#import "AudioToolBox/AudioToolBox.h"
```

Don't forget to add the framework, too.

Comment: Yes, but hasn't that header changed when the iOS 5 came? I can't find it! I'm looking for it on github, where a person has class dumped them. 
This is jailbreak develoPment if I forgOt to mention.

Comment: First, I can't find anything that suggests that header's been deprecated.  Second, it's included in the AudioToolbox.framework which you can access in Build Phases.  There shouldn't be a need for GitHub if you have the SDK.  Third, it may be the <audiounit/audiounit.h> file you want but I think you should really read the docs to make sure you're adding what you want:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/CoreAudioFrameworks/CoreAudioFrameworks.html